# Formula field result is different on object vs in a report

Tags: reporting, formula-field

I have some text formulas on an object called Student Placement. They compare and explain the difference between Fall and Spring GPAs (which are numeric formula fields). If either or both of the GPAs are blank, the text formula should result in "Has Blank." This seems to be working correctly when I view the text fields directly on a Student Placement record:

[image: SP-0004593]

However, viewing the same record (SP-0004593) within a report, it yields "#Error!" in some fields.

[image: Formula fields in a report]

The formula for the "Ch Math GPA" field is as follows, where "F_Math_GPA__c" and "S_Math_GPA__c" are numeric formula fields referring to straight number fields.

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK( F_Math_GPA__c ),ISBLANK(S_Math_GPA__c)),"Has Blank",
IF( F_Math_GPA__c > S_Math_GPA__c, "Decreased",
IF( F_Math_GPA__c = S_Math_GPA__c, "No Change",
IF( F_Math_GPA__c < S_Math_GPA__c, "Increased","Help me!"))))
```

Can anyone help explain this behavior? I'm concerned that it may erode trust with my users!

Update

F_Math_GPA__c:

```
( F_Demonstrates_number_sense__c + 
  F_Develops_and_explains_strategies__c + 
  F_Understands_and_applies_math_thinking__c + 
  F_Math_Effort__c ) / 
  (if(isblank(F_Demonstrates_number_sense__c),0,1)+
   if(isblank(F_Develops_and_explains_strategies__c),0,1)+ 
   if(isblank(F_Understands_and_applies_math_thinking__c),0,1)+ 
   if(isblank(F_Math_Effort__c),0,1)
 )
```

Comment: Would you share one of the formulas that are showing "#Error!"?  Just want to see what the logic is.

Comment: Given that `F_Math_GPA__c` and `S_Math_GPA__c` are also formula fields, this could be a knock-on problem from those formulas. I would suggest posting those, too given that not much can go wrong with `OR(ISBLANK( F_Math_GPA__c ),ISBLANK(S_Math_GPA__c))`. You could also try tweaking (try `ISNULL` instead of `ISBLANK`, or use the `||` operator instead of the `OR` formula in case you've run into a bug of some sort.

Comment: I agree with Peter. It would help to have all reference formulas because any could be contributing to the issue. Part of what you should check to is how null values are displayed. One of the options when setting up a formula field is "null values are blank OR null values are zero". Since you're using the ISBLANK() funtion, make sure all the numeric formula fields are marked as "null values are blank"

Comment: Thanks both for your thoughts. All fields involved are marked as "null values are blank." Here is the formula for F_Math_GPA__c:

`(  F_Demonstrates_number_sense__c + F_Develops_and_explains_strategies__c + F_Understands_and_applies_math_thinking__c + F_Math_Effort__c  ) 
/ 
(if(isblank(F_Demonstrates_number_sense__c),0,1)+ 
if(isblank(F_Develops_and_explains_strategies__c),0,1)+ 
if(isblank(F_Understands_and_applies_math_thinking__c),0,1)+ 
if(isblank(F_Math_Effort__c),0,1))`

Comment: F_Math_GPA__c will divide by zero if all of its operands are blank

Comment: Yes, I know that some of my formulas will result in a divide by zero error, but I don't understand why the error only shows up in the field on a report and not in the field on the record. (see original screenshots)